# How to create a many to many relationship in amplify datastore using schema.graphql

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

```
type StudentCourses
  @model(queries: null)
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: public }])
  @key(name: "byStudent", fields: ["studentID", "courseID"])
  @key(name: "byCourse", fields: ["courseID", "studentID"]) {
  id: ID!
  studentID: ID!
  courseID: ID!
  student: Student! @connection(fields: ["studentID"])
  course: Course! @connection(fields: ["courseID"])
}

type Course
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: public }])
  @key(name: "bySchool", fields: ["schoolID"]) {
  id: ID!
  courseName: String!
  schoolID: ID!
  students: [Student!] @connection(keyName: "byCourse", fields: ["id"])
}

type Student
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: public }])
  @key(name: "bySchool", fields: ["schoolID"]) {
  id: ID!
  studentName: String
  studentEmail: String
  sisID: Int
  schoolID: ID!
  courses: [Course!] @connection(keyName: "byStudent", fields: ["id"])
}
```

I followed the steps in [docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli-legacy/graphql-transformer/connection/#many-to-many-connections) to create  a many to many relationship between student and courses but i keep getting this error **Key byCourse does not exist for model Student** even thought i created a model to connect school and courses. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to omit `keyName` from `Course`, since in `Student` model, you have list of courses, so you can't really have `@key` directive for that.

https://docs.amplify.aws/cli-legacy/graphql-transformer/connection/#many-to-many-connections

```
type Course
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: public }])
  @key(name: "bySchool", fields: ["schoolID"]) {
  id: ID!
  courseName: String!
  schoolID: ID!
  students: [Student!] @connection(fields: ["id"])
}
```

Comment: How do we do the same with the new Transformer v2?  I have set it all up like:

Answer (score -1):

Anyone who is upto V2 of Amplify, they can get guidance from this link
https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#belongs-to-relationship
Updated Flow has the following changes

- You need to add @manyToMany on both tables that are going to join
- This will create a third table by itself and will add Queries and Mutations for it as well.

Comment: Irfan Murtaza, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)